# How can I take text from <input> tag to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a program and it prompts the user to input text. Is there a way I can just take user input from the text box and then have the program take and use that text from there? Here's the code so far:

None of your corrections were working because I didn't tell you the what this program does. This program is supposed to take in a letter and then replace it with another letter encrypting the text, so I think that you need to see the entire code to figure this out;

```js
function encodeFunction() {
  var text = prompt("Enter Text");
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text);
}

function decodeFunction() {
  var text = prompt("Enter Text");
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text, false);
}

function LetterChanges(str, encode = true) {
  let adjust = 1;
  if (!encode) {
    adjust = -1;
  }
}

}
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  let strArray = str.split("");
  let letterChange = strArray.map(function(value, index, array){
    if(str.charCodeAt(index) < 97 || str.charCodeAt(index) > 122){
      return value
    }else{
      return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(index)+adjust)
    }
  });
  
  return letterChange.join(""); 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="EString" name="EString"> <br><br>
</form>
<button onclick="encodeFunction()">Encode String</button>
<button onclick="decodeFunction()">Decode String</button>
<p id="function"></p>
```

Comment: You can simpply use "document.getElementById("EString").value" for get the value from input textbox.

Comment: @amitsaini It didnt work. This is what i did, function decodeFunction() {
  var text = prompt("Enter Text");
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text, false);
}         to this,                                                                                                                 function decodeFunction() {
  document.getElementById("EString").value;
}

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your encode and decode functions, you can change:

```
var text = prompt("Enter Text");
```

to

```
var text = document.getElementById("EString").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get the value of the text input(id='EString') you can use

```
document.getElementById('EString').value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get the `value` of `document.getElementById("EString")`, *e.g.*

```js
function encodeFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("EString").value;
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text);
}

function decodeFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("EString").value;
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text, false);
}

function LetterChanges(str, encode = true) {
  let adjust = 1;
  if (!encode) {
    adjust = -1;
  }
  return str;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="EString" name="EString"> <br><br>
</form>
<button onclick="encodeFunction()">Encode String</button>
<button onclick="decodeFunction()">Decode String</button>
<p id="function"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myChange(){
console.log(document.getElementById("EString").value);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" onchange="myChange()" id="EString" name="EString" style=" width:1000px; height:500px;"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code for your desired result:

```js
    
function encodeFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("EString").value;
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML =      LetterChanges(text);
}

function decodeFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("EString").value;
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text, false);
}

function LetterChanges(str, encode=true) { 
  let adjust = 1;
  if(!encode){
    adjust = -1;
   }
   return adjust;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="EString" name="EString" style=" width:1000px; height:500px;" /> <br><br>
</form>

<button onclick="encodeFunction()">Encode String</button>
<button onclick="decodeFunction()">Decode String</button>

<p id="function"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I made some changes in your code.**

```
<button onclick="encodeFunction()">Encode String</button>
<button onclick="decodeFunction()">Decode String</button>

<p id="function"></p>


<script>
        function encodeFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("EString").value;
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text);
}

function decodeFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("EString").value;
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text, false);
}

function LetterChanges(str, encode=true) { 
  let adjust = 1;
  if(!encode){
    adjust = -1;
  }
return "Text recieved in JavaScript: " + str;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use oninput and onchange attributes in input tag to call javascript function, because oninput is not working in some browsers.